# Two primary keys when creating a table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, open-source, composite-primary-key

I'm new to MySql! I'm trying to create a table with 2 primary key or what is usually called a composite key.

```
CREATE TABLE MovedProduct
(
   MigrationId nvarchar(150)   NOT NULL,
   ContextKey nvarchar(300)  NOT NULL,
   Model varbinary(65535) NOT NULL,
   ProductVersion nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
   primary key(MigrationId,ContextKey)
)
```

but I'm getting an error that I can't figure out.

```
Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

I don't what to decrease the keys size because they can get up to their respective size.

Is there something special I need to do in order to have my table created?

Answer (score 2):

You should reduce you field length for the involved  fields  .. because some charset don't use only one byte for a char but more so .. when these fileds will stored   could exeed  the limit for keys length

eg :

```
CREATE TABLE MovedProduct
(
   MigrationId nvarchar(64)   NOT NULL,
   ContextKey nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL,
   Model varbinary(65535) NOT NULL,
   ProductVersion nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
   primary key(MigrationId,ContextKey)
)
```

you your charset  use 3 bytes for store a char then in your sample you have  3*150 + 3*400 = 1650
instead  3*64 + 3*128   = 576

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need utf8, then explicitly specify latin`:

```
MigrationId varchar(150)  CHARACTER SET latin1  NOT NULL,
ContextKey  varchar(300)  CHARACTER SET latin1  NOT NULL,
```